# locating element via selenium explicitly waiting and without gives 0

Tags: python, selenium

Using this [url](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=1&rh=n%3A1%2Cp_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin%3A8622846011&dc&fs=true&qid=1665559431&rnid=8622845011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin_5&ds=v1%3AgAO0%2BZc%2BC6RthRkqyWzOHmDVufv7JbuCK96Grvjle68)  I want to locate div tags which has attribute `data-asin` . When I use `//div[@data-asin]` in Chrome Inspect mode it gives 21 elements. But while trying to get these elements via Selenium in both ways, explicit wait and direct length gives 0. As I guess Selenium remote browser is unable to get anyone of these elements as a DOM tree. code is below

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#reading from csv file url-s
def readCSV(path_csv):
    df=pd.read_csv(path_csv)
    return df

fileCSV=readCSV(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\urls.csv')
length_of_column_urls=fileCSV['linkamazon'].last_valid_index()

def create_driver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.headless = True
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    # options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

    webdriver_service = Service(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver107v\chromedriver.exe')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

    return driver

#going to urls 1-by-1
def goToUrl_Se(driver):
    global counter
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, length_of_column_urls + 1):
        xUrl = fileCSV.iloc[i, 1]
        print(xUrl,i)
        # going to url(amazn) via Selenium WebDriver
        driver.get(xUrl)
        parse_data()
        counter+=1
    driver.quit()

#fetch-parse the data from url page
def parse_data():
    global asin, title, bookform, priceNewProd,author
    wait=WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=77)

    try:
        x_index=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,'//div[@data-asin]')))###Attention here
        print(len(x_index))
    except:
        y_index=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'//div[@data-asin]')###Anf attention here
        print(len(y_index))

driver=create_driver()
goToUrl_Se(driver)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention XPATH not TAG_NAME:

```
try:
    x_index=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@data-asin]')))###Attention here
    print(len(x_index))
except:
    y_index=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@data-asin]')###Anf attention here
    print(len(y_index))
```